# Parameters in Procedure not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I created the following query:

```
    SELECT Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as 'Total Copies'
    FROM BOOK_COPIES bc
    join BOOK_AUTHORS ba
    on bc.BookId=ba.BookId
    join BOOK b
    on b.BookId=bc.BookId
    join LIBRARY_BRANCH lb
    on bc.BranchId=lb.BranchId where AuthorName='George Orwell' and BranchName='Central'
    group by b.Title
```

From this query I wanted to create a procedure that could search for the amount of book copies of any Author or Branch name, so I created this:

```
    CREATE PROC GetTotalCopies @AuthorName varchar(100), @BranchName varchar(100)
    AS

       SELECT Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as 'Total Copies'
       FROM BOOK_COPIES bc
       join BOOK_AUTHORS ba
       on bc.BookId=ba.BookId
       join BOOK b
       on b.BookId=bc.BookId
       join LIBRARY_BRANCH lb
       on bc.BranchId=lb.BranchId where AuthorName='@AuthorName' and BranchName='@BranchName'
       group by b.Title
```

But when I run it with a Author Name and Branch Name I get empty tables. Anyone know why?
I created this database from the following flowchart:
https://www.learncodinganywhere.com/learningmanagementsystem/links/07_DB/SQL_Drill.pdf
using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for single quotes.  The arguments are already strings.

So, write the query like this:

```
where AuthorName = @AuthorName and BranchName = @BranchName
```

Note:  You might want to consider arguments that function as "all values":

```
where (AuthorName = @AuthorName or @AuthorName is null) and
      (BranchName = @BranchName or @BranchName is null)
```

Comment: For some reason the first where clause wasn't working even without strings. But the second where clause you gave me works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the *single quotes* around the parameter. It will make the parameter as string literal. Though the parameters are string type, the parameters does not require single quotes when they are evaluated

```
where AuthorName=@AuthorName and BranchName=@BranchName
```